# Creating custom permission in data migration

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-permissions

I was trying to create a custom permission in a migration, however after running migrate, the permission was not created in the permission table. Could someone point out what the error was? 
Also I am not sure what I should use as the related model for ContentType as the permission is used for restricting users that can view a page which shows summary of users on the site. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
def add_view_aggregated_data_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    ContentType = apps.get_model('django', 'ContentType')
    Permission = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', model='user')
    permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_view_data',
                                           name='Can view data',
                                           content_type=content_type)
```

Comment: Why would you want to create a permission this way?

Comment: Is this the wrong way to do it? I want to create a permission for a view, how should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the standard way to use custom permissions as described in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions). You will avoid many issues altogether.

> To create custom permissions for a given model object, use the permissions model Meta attribute.

This example model creates a custom permission:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_data', "Can see available data"),
        )
```

> The only thing this does is create those extra permissions when you run `manage.py migrate`. Your code is in charge of checking the value of these permissions when a user is trying to access the functionality provided by the application...

Then you can use the [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator with your view to check for the specific permission:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('myapp.view_data')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Does that mean the permission will be associated with the User model? The part where I was confused is that my permission is only used for restricting access to a view, so I am not sure which model to associate that with. Also, will I be able to add this permission to users in the admin site? Edit: Just realised I cannot edit code on the User model, so where should I put the meta code? I am new to this so I might have a lot of questions...

Comment: What do you mean that the permission will be associated with the User model? All permissions are associated with the User model in essence. If you specifically need to add a permission eg to view users, then that's entirely a different matter and you would need to extend or override the User model. I suppose that your view *will* display the data from at least some model, so you can add the permission to that model.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the association was something like relating the permission to which model will be able to have that permission, but that doesn't really make sense, I guess that was why I got confused. Thanks for the clarification :) So if the view contains data from different models, I only have to add the permission to one model?

Comment: Welcome. It depends on the whole app, you could only add a permission to a single model, or to all models and check against all permissions (safer).

Comment: NOTE: the permission becomes available only at the end of the `migrate` command, so if you have (i.e.) subsequent RunPython migrations which reference the new permission, they won't see the new permission if applied within the same `migrate` command. In that case you'll have to apply them in two stages.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to created a custom permission (read) for all app models. I did this two steps:

1. Create an extended permission from DjangoModelPermissions:

   ```
   class DjangoModelPermissionsExtended(DjangoModelPermissions):
       """
       """
       perms_map = {
           'GET': ['%(app_label)s.read_%(model_name)s'],
           'OPTIONS': [],
           'HEAD': [],
           'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
           'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
           'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
           'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
       }
   ```
2. Put it in **each** view I want to have read permission:

   ```
   class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       permission_classes = (
           DjangoModelPermissionsExtended,
       )
   ```
3. Create a [django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) customread.py:

   ```
   from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
   from project.app import models as app_models
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
   import inspect

   class Command(BaseCommand):
   help = 'Create the read permission to app models'

   def handle(self, *args, **options):
       for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(app_models):
           if inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, models.Model):
               try:
                   self.add_canread(obj)
                   self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(
                       'created permission for %s' % obj
                   ))
               except Exception as e:
                   self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR(
                       'Permission already exists for %s' % obj
                   ))

   def add_canread(self, object_class):
       """This a function that can be executed in order to create
       new permissions (read view) to a class in DB.

       """
       if inspect.isclass(object_class):
           content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(object_class)
           permission = Permission.objects.create(
               codename='read_{}'.format(object_class._meta.model_name),
               name='Can view {}'.format(object_class.__name__),
               content_type=content_type,
           )
       else:
           msg = "The object is not a class"
           print(msg)
   ```
4. Execute it after doing migrations:

   ```
   python manage.py customread
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As of django 1.8 and built-in migrations this is very painless.

1. All you need to do is add the permissions you want to the relevant
   model
2. Run makemigration

   ./manage.py makemigrations
3. run the migration created in the step above

   ./manage.py migrate